# Solução para um erro no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, view, order-by

Galera, poderiam me ajuda eu estou tentando criar uma view "POSICAO_EQUIPES", com uma Consulta que exibe a classificação geral por Equipes, independente de categoria. A consulta deverá exibir o ID do Campeonato, o ID da Equipe, o Nome da Equipe e a soma de quantidade de pontos dos seus pilotos, ordenados por IDCampeonato e Pontos em ordem decrescente. (use o comando JOIN, SUM e Group BY)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Código está assim:

```
create view POSICAO_EQUIPES as
SELECT
  T1.IDCampeonato as 'ID do Campeonato',
  T2.IDEquipe as 'Id da Equipe',
  T2.NomeEquipe as 'Nome da Equipe',
  C.IDClassificacao, SUM (C.pontos) as 'Total de pontos por Equipe', sum (C.pontos + C.CATEGORIA)
FROM
Classificacao C,
pilotoequipe T1
join equipes T2 on (T2.IDEquipe = T1.IDEquipe)
join pilotos T3 on (T3.IDPiloto = T1.IDPiloto);
```

Comment: E qual o erro que, no título da pergunta, você afirma existir. Se está obtendo algum resultado qual o resultado obtido e qual o esperado?

Comment: O erro está no meu código, mas não sei aonde...

Comment: Provavelmente você não deseja uma string e sim fazer quoting. Troque `'` por ` (acento grave) em seus alias_name.

Comment: Já corrigir, mas não resolveu

Comment: Lamento, minha bola de cristal está offline.